# Oracle SQL Trigger on After Update a certain column, How to print a line without raise application error?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am new to MySQL and now I am learning about trigger. I have one table, table1. I am trying to create a trigger for every update executed in address column, I would also like to print a line without raising application error. Here is how my table looks like:

```
create table table1(
  2  ID varchar(9),
  3  Name char(25),
  4  DOB date,
  5  address varchar(20)
  6  )
  7  ;
```

My trigger does not seem to print any output when I update the address.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_UPDATE_ADDRESS
  2  AFTER UPDATE of address ON table1
  3  BEGIN
  4  dbms_output.put_line('Address Column is Updated Successfully');
  5  END;
  6  /
```

Update:

```
 update table1 set address =  '東京' where ID = '144131214';
```

Output:

> 1行が更新されました。 (1 row(s) updated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` you need to execute `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` first - to enable printing the buffer to the screen.

Example:

```
koen>update table1 set address = 'Belgium';

1 row updated.

koen>set serveroutput on size 999999
koen>update table1 set address = 'Belgium';
Address Column is Updated Successfully


1 row updated.

koen>
```

Comment: No problem. Note that you tagged your question as mysql but this is NOT mysql. It is oracle. oracle and mysql are 2 different databases. I think you meant to tag sql instead (sql is the language, mysql is a flavor of database)